# How to enable Diagnostic(DIAG) Mode in ZTE Engage N8000

Tags: cdma

How to put ZTE Cricket Engage N8000 in Diagnostic(DIAG) Mode. I want to use it in DFS CDMA Tool.

Comment: Related SO post - [Android Diagnostic Mode - How to Enable it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24006903/5181313)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it only if your phone is rooted.

Make sure Qualcomm drivers for your phone are installed in computer.

Enter this in Terminal Emulator in your device:

```
su
setprop sys.usb.config diag,adb
```

**Note:** This will work only if your phone's ramdisk has the appropriate configs enabled for the 'diag,adb' property.
If that didn't work, better open **/init.xxxxxxx.usb.rc** (xxxxxxx represents your device's codename or chipname or whatever) and check for properties related to '**diag**'.

Comment: How did you conclude that OP's device is rooted?

Comment: @Firelord Just a guess ;) Anyway, edited the answer to mention it needs root :)